# Mysql 5.7: to retun ids that do not exist

Tags: mysql, select, exists

everybody,

I'm using Mysql 5.7 and I need a query that returns non-existent ids when the ids are between 2000 and 2500.

I can explain better. This query:

> SELECT DISTINCT id FROM table WHERE id BETWEEN 2000 AND 2500;

returns the ids that exist in the table between 2000 and 2500. What I need are the ids that do not exist. How can I do it?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Please add sample data to your question.  It is not clear what you want here.

Comment: You know, that's an infinite set of numbers, right?

Comment: yeah, sorry, I was trying to simplify. I've editted my post: between and